# Jetty Server does not start

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jetty, wicket

I have a problem running jetty server.

```
>>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.velocity.Initializer - Initialized Velocity successfully
[main] WARN org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter - initialization failed, destroying now
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.Application - [wicket.project] destroy: Wicket core library initializer
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.Application - [wicket.project] destroy: DevUtils DebugBar Initializer
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.Application - [wicket.project] destroy: Wicket extensions initializer
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.Application - [wicket.project] destroy: Wicket JMX initializer
[main] INFO org.apache.wicket.Application - [wicket.project] destroy: org.apache.wicket.velocity.Initializer@1453a1c7
[main] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED wicket.project: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: path to '/C:/Users/F%c4%b1rat/Desktop/2/src/itudb1323.db': 'C:\Users\F%c4%b1rat' does not exist
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: path to '/C:/Users/F%c4%b1rat/Desktop/2/src/itudb1323.db': 'C:\Users\F%c4%b1rat' does not exist
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:449)
```

The problem seems like this `C:/Users/F%c4%b1rat/Desktop/2/src/itudb1323.db': 'C:\Users\F%c4%b1rat' does not exist`
The path should be `C:/Users/Fırat/Desktop/2/src/itudb1323.db` however it tries to find `F%c4%b1rat`

Comment: Include what version of Jetty you are using in your question.

Comment: Include how you start Jetty in your question.

Comment: Include how you configured that context for Jetty in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put your workspace into a directory which does not contain Windows-1254 character set (Example: Under `C:/`). This is a temporary solution but it can fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `ı` is interpreted by Java as ...

[`U+0131 LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I character (&#x0131;)`](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder?encoding=numeric&bytes=0xc4%200xb1)

Which is UTF-8 translated from the Windows-1252 codepage as Hex `0xC4 0xB1`, hence the `F%c4%b1rat` part of the path.  Which is required to be URL encoded for the URLClassLoader.

Sounds like you have hit a JVM bug with unicode and/or windows codepage support in the URLClassloader.  Would encourage you to not deploy on these kinds of paths, or upgrade your JVM to see if this is better supported with a later JVM.